# Как сделать чтоб код на pyrogram запоминал историю запросов к гпт

Tags: python, pyrogram

Я сделал код который должен запоминать историю и общаться с пользователями в лс с помощью токена опен аи, но он не хочет запоминать историю сообщений

```py
history = [] 
@app.on_message(filters.private)
async def private_message(client, message):
    if message.chat.id in private_chat_ids_to_exclude or message.from_user.id in users_to_exclude:
        return

    history.append({"role": "user", "content": message.text})

    await client.send_chat_action(chat_id=message.chat.id, action="typing")

    messages = [
        {"role": "system", "content": "Вас зовут Шарик"},
        {"role": "user", "content": message.text}
    ]

    history.append({"role": "user", "content": message.text})

    # Флаг для проверки готовности ответа
    response_ready = False

    while not response_ready:
        response = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=messages,
            max_tokens=750,
            temperature=0.7
        )

        if response.choices and response.choices[0].message.content:
            response_ready = True
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    resp_ai = response.choices[0].message.content.strip()
    history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": resp_ai})

    await message.reply(resp_ai, reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
```

Comment: Что значит не хочет?

Comment: Не запоминает историю

Comment: Вам нужно хранить историю для каждого юзера в БД. Но так же неплохо было бы учесть возможность сброса истории